# GDB core debug suggests pointer passed to function turns NULL after calling

Tags: c, linux, memory, gdb, stack

I know how weird the title may sound.  I cannot reproduce the problem at ease, as it's an R script with many libraries loaded, and it only crashes once a month or even less frequently.  But when it crashes, it always gives the same error on the same line.  I'll skip the R part and show how gdb trace shows me confusing values.

C code snippets from R:

```
// datetime.c
...   SEXP attribute_hidden do_asPOSIXlt(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
...   {
705       SET_STRING_ELT(tzone, 1, mkChar(tzname[0]));
... ...

// envir.c
3723  SEXP mkChar(const char *name)
3724  {
3725      size_t len = strlen(name);
... ...
```

where tzname is a global variable.

Here's gdb core debug:

```
gdb /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R ~/core.30387
(gdb) bt 3
#0  0x00007f1dca844ff1 in __strlen_sse2_pminub () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f1dcb20e8f9 in mkChar (name=0x0) at envir.c:3725
#2  0x00007f1dcb1dc225 in do_asPOSIXlt (call=<optimized out>,
op=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>,
    env=<optimized out>) at datetime.c:705
(More stack frames follow…)
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x00007f1dcb20e8f9 in mkChar (name=0x0) at envir.c:3725
3725    envir.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) p name
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x00007f1dcb1dc225 in do_asPOSIXlt (call=<optimized out>, op=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>,
    env=<optimized out>) at datetime.c:705
705 datetime.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) p tzname[0]
$2 = 0x4cf39c0 "CST"
```

The caller calls mkChar() with value 0x4cf39c0, however, according to gdb, it turns to NULL (0x0) in callee's context.  I know this is probably a memory issue, but if some R library has messed up the memory, tzname should be zero or invalid.  What confuses me here is that it seems the parameter (pointer tzname[0]) passed to mkChar somehow "changed" (if it's really a change) to NULL after the call.

Any idea on where to further look into?

Answer (score 1):

> The caller calls mkChar() with value 0x4cf39c0

You don't *know* that.

The value in `tzname[0]` *currently* is `0x4cf39c0`, but may have had a different value at the time of the call.

If the application is multithreaded, you may have hit [this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14023) bug.

Comment: In fact, that's what puzzled me most.  Multithread is apparently the usual suspect here, but R is not multithreaded.

Comment: @Sunfucius "R is not multithreaded" -- but it can load extensions, which can be multithreaded. What does `info thread` say?

Comment: Right, it shows another thread:
(gdb) info thread
  Id   Target Id         Frame
  2    Thread 0x7f1dba633700 (LWP 31629) 0x00007f1dcaaaed42 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
* 1    Thread 0x7f1dcb9497c0 (LWP 30387) 0x00007f1dca844ff1 in __strlen_sse2_pminub () from /lib64/libc.so.6